# Writing a callback function for a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, callback, html-select

I have a bootstrap modal confirmation where I want to display the currently selected value of a html select list as well as a value by passing in a variable.

I asked this SO question and received a good answer here about [displaying two values from the same html select list for a JavaScript confirmation popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815921/html-select-list-get-text-value-by-passing-in-a-variable). However, I now need to replace the JavaScript confirmation with a bootstrap modal.

Here is the html select list:

```
<select name="language_code" id="id_language_code">
    <option value="ar">Arabic - العربية</option>
    <option value="bg">Bulgarian - Български</option>
    <option value="zh-CN">Chinese (Simplified) - 中文 (简体)‎</option>
    <option value="en" selected="selected">English (US)</option>
    <option value="fr-CA">French (Canada) - français (Canada)‎</option>
</select>
```

I can display two language values on the bootstrap modal, using the following code:

```
$( "#submit_buttonA" ).attr('update-confirm', 'Are you sure you want to change the language of the website from ' + $('#id_language_code option[value=' + '{{ user.get_profile.language_preference }}' +  ']').text() + ' to ' + $('#id_language_code option:selected').text() + '?');
```

The above code line always returns the 2nd language value **$('#id_language_code option:selected').text()** (which is marked as selected="selected") as **English (US)** on the bootstrap modal, even if the user has selected **Bulgarian - Български**.

I have read up on this and believe that this will require a JavaScript callback function because the bootstrap modal is asynchronous, while the JavaScript confirm() is not asynchronous.

Is this correct? I have tried writing a call back function to return the value of the html select list that the user has selected, but it does not work. I am not sure if this is the correct approach or that my code skills are not good enough.

**Can someone show me how to write this call back function and explain how it works, because I am really confused on how to get this to work?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bootstrap's modal class already have below events for hooking into modal functionality.

1. **show**   - This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
2. **shown**  - This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for css transitions to complete).
3. **hide**   - This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.
4. **hidden** - This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for css transitions to complete).

You can use the above events as

```
 $('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
    //your code to display the message
 })
```

Hope this will solve your problem !!

**EDIT 1 :**

The real problem is with jquery selector `$('#id_language_code option:selected').text();`
Use 
`var selectedValue = $('#id_language_code').val():` which will give you the currently selected value inside the select box. and you can use `$('#id_language_code option[value=' + selectedValue + ']').text();` to get the text which is selected by the user.

You don't need to go for the Call back function for your problem.

Good Day

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. I want to display a value in a bootstrap modal. The display of the modal is not an issue.

Comment: @user1261774 But you need to sync the selected values into the text of the modal whenever you (re)display the modal. "whenever you (re)display the modal" = `show`/`shown` event

Comment: @user1261774 "I want to display a value in a bootstrap modal" whats the confusing part in the display?? can you explain little bit more ?. I'm looking forward to find out a solution for your problem

Comment: Navas Basheer, If the user selects **Bulgarian - Български** from the html select list & then clicks on the form submit button, the **displayed** value of the select list should be displayed (not the **selected** value) in the modal message. Currently, the wrong value marked as "selected" is always displayed, which is English (US) as show above in the example select list. I want to display Bulgarian - Български. Does this make sense? This has me really confused as to why I cannot get the "Bulgarian - Български" value to the modal message.

Comment: @user1261774 now I got what's your question is !!!! the problem is with jquery selector `$('#id_language_code option:selected').text()` use `var selectedValue = $('#id_language_code').val()` which will give you the currently selected value inside the select box. and you can use `$('#id_language_code option[value=' + selectedValue +  ']').text();` to get the text which is selected by the user. Let me know your result after trying this :)

Comment: Navas Basheer, unfortunately I had already tried this approach. The "selectedValue" you recommend returns the selected value of **en** (because **English (US)** is selected) despite selecting **Bulgarian - Български** from the html select list.

Comment: No. Wait! This does work!! Stupid me!! Playing and tweaking the code fixed the issue with the suggestion from Navas Basheer. THANKYOU NAVAS BASHEER. edit your answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Please note that in the current version of bootstrap modal, the onShown event on works like this: on("shown.bs.modal",...